# Only allow several several values for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, authorization, has-many

I have a homepage for my sports club wich consists of several departments.
At the moment the authorization system is realized by using cancan.

Each department can have multiple users and each user can belong to multiple departments:

#department.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

\user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
```

This works very well. But I want to have a possibility to administrate this association in the User form. There I have a group of checkboxes for each department. This is realized by this line (using simple_form):

```
<%= f.association :departments,
            :as => :check_boxes,
            :collection => Department.specific.order('name' => :asc),
            :label_method => :name,
            :value_method => :id %>
```

Now I only want to allow to change several values. On client side I can achieve this by simply hiding or disabling some checkboxes. But this is not save on server when I do not check it again.
The checkbox values will be transmitted by an array of ids. There is a huge potential to manipulate ids in this array.
On the server side I would have to check if the current user has the permission to assign a user to the departments. When he has no rights I need to leave this association unchanged.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

I am using Rails 4.0 with strong parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So your question is basically about `server-side validation` -- checking if a user can edit an association on the server side?

I'd look at setting dynamic strong params to start with, with a view to integrate into the model if it works:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def update
     @item = Model.find(params[:id])
     @params = (can? :update, @item) ? "" : "departments: []"
end

private

def controller_params
   params.require(:controller).permit(:attributes, @params.to_sym)
end
```